# ios http POST (Data and Image): Image not getting posted

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, cocoa-touch, http-post

I used the following code to PUSH an image and data into a server. The data is being sent but the image is not received in the server. Can someone spot me if there is an error in my below code which I have used:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@action=savesign",MainURL]];

// set up the form keys and values (revise using 1 NSDictionary at some point - neater than 2 arrays)
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user",@"poll",nil];
NSArray *vals = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:user,pollid,nil];

// set up the request object
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Add content-type to Header. Need to use a string boundary for data uploading.
NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//create the post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

//add (key,value) pairs (no idea why all the \r's and \n's are necessary ... but everyone seems to have them)
for (int i=0; i<[keys count]; i++) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",[keys objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[vals objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];


NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_Signfield.image);
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"myPngFile.png\"\r\n", _Signfield.image] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// set the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

This is the response from the server

```
{"status":"failure","error":[],"user":0}
```

And when I login and check the data is there but not the image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you perform a file upload via HTTP POST, the data that gets transmitted over the wire looks like this:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Content-Length: 17918
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Host: example.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.7.2

--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

Diphin-Das
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="poll"

1
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="myPNGFile.png"
Content-Type: image/png

[Binary PNG image data not shown]
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY--
```

The first seven lines are the HTTP headers that describe the request to server, including:

- The HTTP request method (`POST`)
- The resource being requested (`/upload`)
- The HTTP protocol version (`HTTP/1.1`)
- The length of the request body (`Content-Length: 17918`)
- The type of data included in the request body (`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=0xKhTmLbOuNdArY`)

That last one is interesting. By setting the content type to `multipart/form-data`, we're allowed to include a mix of different data types into the request body. The `boundary` tells the server how each of the form values are separated in the request body.

The form values in the request body are described using a simple structure:

```
--[boundary marker]
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="[parameter name]"
Content-Type: [parameter value MIME type]

[parameter value]
```

The Content-Type header is optional if the parameter value is alphanumeric, but for other data types (images, videos, documents, etc.) it's required. The end of request body is signaled by a *terminating boundary marker* which is a standard boundary marker suffixed with a double-hyphen, e.g. `--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY--`. New line characters (\r\n) are used to delimit the various elements of the content parts.

There can be other elements to the form values in a multipart POST request. If you're interested, you can read about them in [RFC 2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt).

In order to upload a file from an Objective-C, you need to craft the request body to that specification outlined above. I've taken the code from your question and refactored it to function correctly & added a few explanatory notes along the way.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{ @"user": user, @"poll": pollid };
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_Signfield.image);

NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@action=savesign",MainURL]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSString *kNewLine = @"\r\n";

// Note that setValue is used so as to override any existing Content-Type header.
// addValue appends to the Content-Type header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// Add the parameters from the dictionary to the request body
for (NSString *name in params.allKeys) {
    NSData *value = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", params[name]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@%@", boundary, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"", name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // For simple data types, such as text or numbers, there's no need to set the content type
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kNewLine, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:value];
    [body appendData:[kNewLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// Add the image to the request body
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@%@", boundary, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"myPngFile.png\"%@", @"image", kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/png"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kNewLine, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[kNewLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Add the terminating boundary marker to signal that we're at the end of the request body
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

Comment: I am not really getting the concept on using this. I tried many link in stack overflow and still not clear on who to use this.
Can u help me with a link with the complete concept og the post http?

Comment: @DhipinDas I've rewritten my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much neilco...i been working on a big project and been stuck on this thing for days...
Your code really worked. And thanks for the info on the concept of this too.
I am so excited so i thing u deserve a 50+...
Which i will award u in 11 hours as bounty will be available by then...:)
Thanks once again.