# iOS upload image php + mysql

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I got a question. I searched for it on the internet, but couldn't find a good answer.

I like to upload an image to a mysql table, a longblob field. I have to get some post data in it also. (Username and pass and stuff).

I want to do this from an iOS app in xCode. So does anyone have the code I have to implement on the iOS side and on the server (php) side?

Comment: using standard html(5) will work on all major bowsers and iOS.
The only thing that could be specific is the css to display things nicely on a mobile device (aka responsive)
see here http://www.codepool.biz/tech-frontier/html5/take-a-photo-and-upload-it-on-mobile-phones-with-html5.html with some extra like <input ... accept="image/*" capture="camera" /> that allows to upload directly from the phone's camera

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it in an app, I'll add it to the question

Comment: run your app in html ;)  what does the app has to do?  iOS apps have full access to sockets/http protocol, but makes things more complex then simple html.

Comment: html mode is not possible :), it has to be in xCode

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-objective-c  Btw, 5 seconds of googling would've let to the same result, using the terms "post request cocoa" ;)

Comment: Yeah.. But it doesn't give me the code for the image upload, because it's different and also not the php code.

Comment: php side is standard file upload as on this example http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: i'm guessing you'll save yourself the work of managing a session, so you'll probably send over user/pass word on each upload. You'll get all this in $_POST array

Comment: But how do you put it in the mysql database as a blob file? And load it back to an image?

Comment: probably an easy way is to use base64_encode to not have to manage binary data... why do you want to have image in the db? here you can find clues on how to manage binary blob http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html  but the usual way is to store the file in the filesystem and just put in mysql the name of the file.  it will make your life easier when you want to get that file back out!

Comment: Because it is like a contact image, so it is easy to get the image from the database and you don't have to worry about filenames?

Comment: it's easier to create your filename... as simple as using a number like the userid... or last_insert_id

Comment: if you store image in db, you'll have to manage getting it out weather it's a gif, png, jpg...

Comment: if it's in a folder, can be accessed by direct http... simple and will work in app and site

Comment: So I have to do this:
In xCode: postrequest = email=%@&pass=%@&image=%@ 

and in php:
$files = $_FILES['image']; and then the moving to the dir?

Comment: or am i wrong with this?

Comment: sounds right.  you'll probably have to use the php function move_uploaded_file to get it safely from the /tmp/ folder

Comment: And how do I represent the image? Like the NSData from the iOS storage?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have this code now, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php
require_once("Database.php");
$con = getConnection();
session_start();

$email = $_POST['email'];

$contact = $_POST['contactID'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$email = stripslashes($email);
$contact = stripslashes($contact);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = md5($password);
$sql="SELECT ID FROM User WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

//echo $id ." <br/>";
//echo $count;

if($count==1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $id = $row->ID;

}
// Make sure the user actually
// selected and uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {

    // Temporary file name stored on the server
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }


} else {
    print "No image selected/uploaded";
}


?>
```

for my php file. And for my xcode upload:

```
-(void) uploadImage: (SparkContact *) contact
{
    NSString *type = @"upload";
    NSString *email = self.fileController.user.email;
    NSString *password = self.fileController.user.password;
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:contact.image];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *post =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&email=%@&password=%@&contactID=%@&image=%@",email,password,contact.userid,data];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[postData length]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://spark-app.freeiz.com/addImage.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];


    ContactSyncObject *obj = [[ContactSyncObject alloc] initWithType:type withContact:contact];
    obj.fileController = self.fileController;
    [obj startSync:theRequest];
}
```

And the contactsyncobject does the request sending and handling the response. But as response I get: "No image selected/uploaded"

Comment: looks like the uploaded image is encoded in $_post['image'] in ascii and not dealt as uploaded file (like with a file upload with a html form), you will have to adapt php code to create a file from $_post['image'] and not from $_FILE reference.  can't tell you how you will revert NSASCIIStringEncoding. The other option is to find a way to add header contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" then I guess php will create $_FILE reference

Comment: perhaps this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247423/ios-http-post-data-and-image-image-not-getting-posted

Comment: Thank you very very much!! It worked with some tweaking!

Comment: might be nice to post your working code now so others could find it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for my problem

The Objective-C code:

```
NSString *email = self.fileController.user.email;
NSString *password = self.fileController.user.password;
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:contact.image];
if(image == nil){
    //UNKNOWN IMAGE
    //image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.png"];
    return;
}

//The $_POST parameters you want to add
NSDictionary *params = @{ @"email": email, @"contact": contact.userid, @"password": password };
//The image to data
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
//your url
NSString *urlString = @"http://spark-app.freeiz.com/addImage.php";


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSString *kNewLine = @"\r\n";

// Note that setValue is used so as to override any existing Content-Type header.
// addValue appends to the Content-Type header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// Add the parameters from the dictionary to the request body
for (NSString *name in params.allKeys) {
    NSData *value = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", params[name]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@%@", boundary, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"", name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // For simple data types, such as text or numbers, there's no need to set the content type
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kNewLine, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:value];
    [body appendData:[kNewLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// Add the image to the request body
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@%@", boundary, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"myPngFile.png\"%@", @"image", kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/png"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kNewLine, kNewLine] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[kNewLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Add the terminating boundary marker to signal that we're at the end of the request body
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
//Now start the request (asynchronous or synchronous)
```

The PHP code:
    //change this to the path the image has to have
    $uploadfile = "path to new image" . ".png|.jpg|...";

```
// selected and uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {



    // Temporary file name stored on the server

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

    } else {

        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";

    }





} else {

    print "No image selected/uploaded";

}
```